# How to drive the CDF of random variable $Z$ define by $ Z=\frac{X_iX_j}{2X_i+X_j} $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am working in wireless communication and some times we use the PDFs and CDFs of random variables.

So I have read a paper and I found the derivation of CDF and PDF of random variable, but I did not understand the steps of the proof.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ two random variable with PDFs 
$$
f_{X_i}(x)=\frac{m_i^{m_i}}{\Omega_i^{m_i}\Gamma(m_i)}x^{m_i-1}e^{-\frac{m_ix}{\Omega_i}}.
$$ 
 i want to find the CDF of random variable $Z$ define by 
$$
Z=\frac{X_iX_j}{2X_i+X_j}
$$

Now the athours of paper use the following steps:

\begin{align}\label{}
F_Z(z)=&\mathbb{P}\left\{Z\leq z\right\}  \\
      =&\mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{X_iX_j}{2X_i+X_j}\leq z\right\} \\
      \stackrel{(a)}{=}&\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left\{\frac{X_iX_j}{2X_i+X_j}\leq z|X_i\right\}f_{X_i}(X_i)dX_i\\
\stackrel{(b)}{=}& \int_{0}^{z}
\mathbb{P}\left\{X_j\geq\frac{2zX_i}{X_i-z}|X_i\right\}
f_{X_i}(X_i)dX_i\\
&+
\int_{z}^{\infty}
\mathbb{P}\left\{X_j\leq\frac{2zX_i}{X_i-z}|X_i\right\}
f_{X_i}(X_i)dX_i\\
=&I_1(z)+I_2(z)
\end{align} 
where 
$$
I_1(z)\stackrel{(c)}{=}\int_{0}^{z}f_{X_i}(X_i)dX_i
$$

$$
I_2(z)\stackrel{(d)}{=}\int_{z}^{\infty}F_{X_j}(\frac{2zX_i}{X_i-z})f_{X_i}(X_i)dX_i.
$$

My questions is are

Firs which low of probability is used in step (a)?.

Why hi divide integral in two range, from $0$ to $z$ and from $z$ to $\infty$

Finally please some detail on steps (b), (c) and (d).

Thanks

Comment: For step (a): the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). And for step (b), because the sign is different in the numerator $X_i-z$ depending on which side of $z$ you are, hence the inequality sign has to be carefully adapted as well.

Comment: Hi, I did not understand this problem of sing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more detail on (b):

$$\frac{X_iX_j}{2X_i+X_j}\leq z \Leftrightarrow X_iX_j \leq 2zX_i+zX_j$$

and

$$X_iX_j \leq 2zX_i+zX_j \Leftrightarrow X_j(X_i-z) \leq 2zX_i \; .$$

Now, in the last step, you have two possible cases: $X_i>z$ or $X_i < z$. If $X_i < z$ then the inequality is trivially true (because the $X_i$ are positive r.v.) and thus has probability 1. Hence why you end up with (c). The other case gives you (d).

Comment: So you mean that  $P\left(X_j\leq \frac{2z}{X_i-z}\right)=1$ for  $X_i\leq z$ otherwise Non?

Comment: Why we flip $<$ to $>$ in interval $[0,z]$?

Comment: Say we have $-3<-2$ and we want to carry over the $-2$. If you don't flip when carrying over the $-2$ you'd get $3/2 < 1$.